# How to check if a sequence of integers is in a list

Tags: python, list

I want the program to continue executing until every element on the list is a string.
That is

```
li = [1, 2, 6, 'h', 'y', 'h', 'y', 4]
```

should stop when

```
li = [all elements type are strings]
```

```
li = [1, 2, 6, 'h', 'y', 'h', 'y', 4]

while '''there are still numbers in the list''':
    #code keeps on executing and updating li[] with string input
else:
    # output the list with no numbers
```

This is what I have tried, but if the `first[0]` and and `last[7]` element becomes a string, the while loop goes to the last else condition even with `int` type present in the list. if done sequentially, it works fine.

```
li = [8, 2, 6, 'h', 'y', 'h', 'y', 4]

for a in li:
    while a in li:
        if type(a) == int:
            x = int(input('Position: '))
            entry = input('Enter: ')
            li.pop(x)
            li.insert(x, entry)
            print(li) # to see what's happening
            li = li
    else:
        print('Board is full')

print(li)
```

But, I don't want it sequentially.
Therefore, it should continue if

```
li = [c, 2, 6, 'h', 'y', 'h', 'y', f]
```

and stop when

```
li = [a, b, c, 'h', 'y', 'h', 'y', d]
```

all strings

Comment: Make a lambda of type(x)==int, use it with the builtin function "all" (computationally intensive for a large list, but fine here)

Comment: Your overall loop should be "while not done", so no other looping mechanism is needed, if I understood correctly. Right now, your while loop doesn't do anything - it just checks if a is in li, which is always true because you got a from li and never change it.

Comment: You are right @KennyOstrom. The condition always remain true

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all` or `any` in conjunction with `string.isnumeric()` to check this

```py
li = ['a', 1, 2]
while any(str(ele).isnumeric() for ele in li):
    modify li ...
```

Comment: Thanks, although this didn't work for me. But you gave me a head start :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution you asked for is possible. But one piece of advice while writing in python, is to avoid doing type checking explicitly (type(a) == int). below is a simple solution.

```
import string
import random
letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters) #swapping data
xe = [8, 2, 6, 'h', 'y', 'h', 'y', 4]
for i in range(len(xe)):
    try:
        xe[i].upper()
    except:
        xe.pop(i)
        xe.insert(i,letter)
print(xe)
```

Comment: You should avoid bare `except` because it catches stuff like `SystemExit`.

Comment: duely noted @gmds

Comment: This strikes me as a very odd use of try/except. The call to `upper` is doing nothing except to act as an implicit type check - and explicit is better than implicit. Just do `if not isinstance(xe[i], str):` (or `basestr` in python 2). Also the `pop` + `insert` would be more clearly and simply written `xe[i] = letter`.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your great contribution,it's helpful. But I was thinking it's more helpful to play with an objects interface by using it's method ( in this case upper) than type checking. And thanks for the pop + insert hint

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, h, y, 5, g, 3]
length = len(li)
while count != length:
    for row in li:
    if type(row) == int:
        li.pop(row)
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Geckos gave me a clue. Thank you for that. I found out that using isinstance with any() solves the problem

```
li = ['a', 1, 2]
while any(isinstance(element, int) for element in li):
       #code goes here...
```